# How can I get a list of all installed apps?

Tags: android, package-managers

Help! All the same the black screen. Show as it is necessary to add a code. Thanks.
I use such code:

```
package com.tipfile;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;


public class dop extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dop);
    PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    ArrayList<ResolveInfo> list = (ArrayList<ResolveInfo>) 
    pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    for (ResolveInfo rInfo : list) {
    System.out.println("Installed Applications " + rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString());
    }
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    listView.setAdapter(aa);
}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    listView.setAdapter(aa);
```

You dont initialize `aa` with any data hence the black screen.

You can build a `List<String>` variable from  `ArrayList<ResolveInfo> list = (ArrayList<ResolveInfo>)` and use the [ArrayAdapter constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20java.util.List%3CT%3E%29) that accepts a list to fill `aa`

**EDIT**

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<ResolveInfo> list = (ArrayList<ResolveInfo>) pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
for (ResolveInfo rInfo : list) {
    System.out.println("Installed Applications " + rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString());
myList.add(rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString());
}

ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList);
listView.setAdapter(aa);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new
ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
```

Change these lines into

```
ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new
ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
```